# Assign value to variable before ajax call runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the variable being passed on the ajax call. The ajax call uses the default value of the variable maybe because it runs asynchronously.

#### jQuery

```js
$(".add-spouse").on("click", function(){
    var spouse_ids = [];
    var last_id = 0;
    var spouse_wrapper = $('#spouse_wrapper');

    if($(".spouse_info").length){
        $(".spouse_info").each(function(){
            spouse_ids.push($(this).data("id"));
        });

        last_id = Math.max.apply(Math, spouse_ids);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/spouses/create',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: last_id
        },
        success: function($result){
            spouse_wrapper.append($result);
        }
    });

    console.log(last_id);

});
```

The `id` being passed always on the ajax call is `0`. I console log and I get incrementing value `0`, `1`, `2`, etc, but when I check the parameter passed on the ajax call, it is always `0`. How can I pass the value of `id` on the ajax call before it runs?

Refer below for the screenshots.

This is the console log:

[image]

And this is the query string parameter received by the ajax call
[image]

As you can see, on the console log, the value incremented from 0 to 1. But on the query string parameter (refer on the left side of the image), the first one being passed is 0, and on the second it is still 0.

Comment: Check with the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make sure the following is not the case: _"Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests."_

Comment: are you sure  wrapper.length is not 0 ,

Comment: The network tab screenshot you're showing is calling `create`, not `new`

Comment: @AhmedSunny Initially it is 0. But the ajax call appends new contents, so the count should increase by 1 every click.

Comment: @EricLease That was a typo. It was create. I've updated it to avoid confusion.

Comment: If possible, please provide a working code snippet in the question so we can assist further. Currently debugging your code without proper context isn't what this forum is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `.spouse_info` elements are never updated?

The Ajax call appends items to the `spouse_wrapper`, which is not being used to query it's children?

I do not see a direct flaw, other than the fact that the array is never larger than 0.

Edit: Since I do not know what is exactly causing it, let's split up some things:

```
$(".add-spouse").on("click", function(){
    var spouse_ids = [];
    var last_id = 0;
    var spouse_wrapper = $('#spouse_wrapper');

    if($(".spouse_info").length){
        $(".spouse_info").each(function(){
            spouse_ids.push($(this).data("id"));
        });

        last_id = Math.max.apply(Math, spouse_ids);
    }

    const ajaxData = {
        url: '/spouses/create',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: last_id
        },
        success: function($result){
            spouse_wrapper.append($result);
        }
    };
    console.log(ajaxData);
    $.ajax(ajaxData);

    console.log(last_id);

});
```

Comment: The array gets larger every time I hit the click event, that's why on the console log, the value increases; from 0 it became 1. The problem is, the ajax call always receives 0 every time I hit on the click event.

By the way, the element that is inserted on the spouse_wrapper is the spouse_info element. So initially there is no spouse_info element. If I hit the click event, it inserts one spouse_info element. And there can be many spouse_info elements inside the spouse_wrapper depending on how many click events being hit.

Comment: You can add some additional console logging then. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like a little mistake on my part. It was my last_id that was not assigned with the incremented value.

It should be:
last_id = Math.max.apply(Math, spouse_ids) + 1;